# Norton's Circuit of dependent source

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I want to know whether the two circuit given are equivalent? Explicitly I want to know when can we use Norton's transform for dependent source?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU7P57.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your two circuits, the dependent voltage source branch is transformed to a dependent current source paralleled with a resistor. It's "source transformation" and is an application of "Norton's Theorem". Source transformation also applies to dependent sources. So, the two circuits are equivalent.

Comment: thanks but i saw circuit we couldn't use Norton's theorem easily yes i know we can always can use it but in dependent sources for example a current of resistor not changed.do you got my mean?

Comment: Please says "slowly", your words is too long :)

Comment: :D for example if we have dependent voltage source with resistor and want to write KCL in node if we convert voltage source to current source we should put current of resistor in past state.

Comment: You mean you will do node voltage analysis on the transformed circuit? There is two method: 1>. Do it as normal, the current on the current source and current on the resistor's sum will equal the circuit before transformation. 2>. Make the current source and the resistor's parallel to a "super node", please refer to: Fundamentals of Electric Circuits by Sadiku, Matthew.